Adobe indesign script to apply stroke to all the frames in document
I need to automate some process in Indesign, therefore I need a javascript script with simple feature: select all frame objects (no matter what kind of a content: both text and image), and add a stroke property to them. 3 px black stroke, for example.
It must be a simple task, but I am new at javascript. I've tried to modify other similar script, but It doesn't work:
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var selection = app.selection;
var selectionLength = selection.length;

var myColor =  myDocument.colors.item("C=0 M=0 Y=0 K=100");

try {
        myColor.name;
    } catch (e) {
        // Doesn't exist; add it.
        myColor = myDocument.colors.add({name: "C=0 M=0 Y=0 K=100", colorValue: [0, 0, 0, 100], model: ColorModel.PROCESS, space: ColorSpace.CMYK});

}

for (var n = 0; n <  selectionLength ; n++) {

    var mySelection = app.selection;

    mySelection.strokeWeight = 3;
    mySelection.enableStroke = true;
    mySelection.strokeColor = myColor;
    mySelection.strokeTint = 100;
    mySelection.strokeAlignment = StrokeAlignment.INSIDE_ALIGNMENT;

}


This script will select all frames and add a 3pt stroke that is black. For the script to work, the script assumes that you have a “Black” color swatch defined in your document. If you have a different name for your black swatch or if you want to use a different color, you’ll need to adjust the strokeColor variable accordingly.
// Target InDesign
#target indesign

// Function to apply stroke to all frames
function applyStrokeToAllFrames(doc, strokeWeight, strokeColor) {
    // Iterate over all page items
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.allPageItems.length; i++) {
        var item = doc.allPageItems[i];
        // Check if the item is a graphic or text frame
        if (item instanceof TextFrame || item instanceof Rectangle || item instanceof Oval || item instanceof Polygon) {
            // Apply stroke weight and color
            item.strokeWeight = strokeWeight;
            item.strokeColor = doc.swatches.item(strokeColor);
        }
    }
}

// Main script
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    // Get the active document
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    // Define stroke weight and color
    var strokeWeight = 3; // 3 px stroke weight
    var strokeColor = "Black"; // Stroke color
    // Apply stroke to all frames
    applyStrokeToAllFrames(doc, strokeWeight, strokeColor);
} else {
    alert("No documents are open. Please open a document and try again.");
}

